# jqgrid getting id after sorting grid

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I want to get the id of a row when user select that row. I used onSelectRow to get the id:

```
jQuery("#dataTable").jqGrid({
    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/groupManagement/loadGroups.htm",
    direction: "rtl",
    recordpos: "left",
    .
    .
    .
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        .
        .
        .
```

The above code works well and I can get the id of selected row. However, sorting a column (which change the order of rows) doesn't affect the id of onSelectRow. For instance, if the sorting have moved the second row to fifth row of the grid, I get 2 in onSelectRow function for that row (I expect 5). How can I fix my issue??

TY.

Comment: You are confusing `id` with `index`.

Comment: How can I get the index?

Comment: Try `var index = $("#" + id).index();`

Comment: try this: `$('#dataTable').find('.ui-state-highlight').index()`.

Comment: The plugin is slightly barmy in that the `ondblClickRow` event fires its handler with `(rowid, iRow, iCol, e)`, where `iRow` is the index you want. IMHO, `onSelectRow` should give the same parameters.

Comment: @javad: Sorry, but `id` should stay unchanged if you fill the grid correctly. The input data *have to* contains `id` information. Only if the data have no ids jqGrid assign integer values 1,2,3... as rowid. So could you append your question with the JavaScript code (including `colModel`) and the test data (at least 1-2 rows of data). What part of the data are native **unique** id of the row?

Answer (score 0):

You can get any column/attribute you want by doing this:

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
   var selectedColumnValue = $('#dataTable').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'ColumnNameToGet');
},
```